# Add component on button click

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am making a front end application using typescript and react. I have a component A which amongst other html elements has a textbox. I want to add this component A on click of a button. So if the user clicks the button multiple times, i want a new component A to be created on every click. Also I want to be able to store the text data so that I can later fetch it and process it.

I tried to make a list of this component but it gives me an error.

```
interface State {
  componentList?: ComponentA[];
}

export class ComponentList extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
  }

  public onClick(event) {
    const componentList = this.state.componentList;
    this.setState({
      componentList: componentList.concat(<ComponentA key= 
         {componentList.length} />)
    });
  }

  public render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <button onClick={this.onClick}>Add component</button>
              {this.state.componentList.map(function(component, index) 
              {
                  return ComponentA
              })}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to make two changes in your code.
First initialise your state in the constructor,

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
    this.state = { componentList: [] }
  }
```

So that react can track that data.

Second thing is, you are returning wrong item from the map in the render function.
Try returning `component`, which is different copies of `<ComponentA ../>` that you pushed every time you clicked the button,

```
  public render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <button onClick={this.onClick}>Add component</button>
              {this.state.componentList.map(function(component, index) 
              {
                  return component;
              })}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep the component count in the state:

```js
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
    this.state = {
        numComponents: 0
    }
}
```

Add a new function which creates an array of the component for rendering later:

```js
clickedComponents = () => {
    let componentArray = [];
    for (let i=0; i<this.state.numComponents; i++) {
        componentArrays.push(<ComponentA />);
    }
    return componentArray;
}
```

Increment the component count with your onClick function:

```js
public onClick(event) {
    this.setState({numComponents: this.state.numComponents + 1});
}
```

Render the component array:

```js
public render() {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <button onClick={this.onClick}>Add component</button>
            {this.clickedComponents()}
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```